# How to create .exe file in Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2012

Tags: c#, windows, visual-studio-2008, sql-server-2012

How to create `.exe` file in Visual Studio 2008 and SQL Server 2012? I am trying to create an `.exe` file for my C# Windows application, I am using microsoft SQL Server Management Studio 2012 as database.

Then only I can run my application in another machine also.

Thanks in advance...

Comment: Try the steps from this site : http://vijirajkumar.blogspot.in/2010/03/create-setup-and-deployment-project.html

Answer (score 1):

1. Create a new project
2. Specify Console Application or Windows Forms Application or any other "Application"
3. Write you code.
4. Compile your code. This will create an exe.

Note: You probably need to build an installer or deployment package and not just copy over the exe to another computer because there may be missing dependencies.

It may help you to read a "getting started in Visual Studio" tutorial.

Cheers.

Answer (score 1):

Try http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/568476/Creating-an-MSI-Setup-Package-for-Csharp-Windows

You cant find complete solution for make .exe.

Answer (score 1):

We can implement auto attach database just use the connection string following.

1)       Add a folder named ”DB” to the project, and copy the database file into it after you detach it from your sql server.

2)       Change your connection string like this:

```
<connectionStrings>
    <add name="WindowsFormsApplication1.Properties.Settings.BabakConnectionString"
        connectionString="Data Source=.;AttachDbFilename=|DataDirectory|\DB\DataBase1.mdf;Initial Catalog=test;Integrated Security=True"
        providerName="System.Data.SqlClient" />
</connectionStrings>
```

3)       After these, the database file will auto attach to the sql server when you run your application, and the database name is “test”, you can open the sql server management studio to find it.

In addition, you can find the connection in the app.config file through the solution explorer in vs2010. And you also can find this file under your project. With these information, you can find it and modify it.

Answer (score 0):

You can see your EXE file in you project's working folder.Open working folder>Bin>Debug>Exe file will be there.Build your solution first

Answer (score -1):

Dont make anybody fool,there is options to create setup wizard of your application both in visual studio 2013 and 2012